# How do I return a function inside of a setOnItemClickListener in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

I would like to return a boolean for a function inside of a switch inside of an item onClickListener. How exactly would I do that?
This is my code:

```java
public void testForItemClick()
    {
        final Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllData("Main_Values");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Celebrity celebrity = unpurchasedCelebrities.get(position);
                int money = cursor.getInt(1);
                if (money < celebrity.getPrice())
                    showPurchaseSnackbar("$TooExpensive");
                else
                {
                    switch (celebrity.getCharacteristic()) {
                        case "c":
                            myDb.updateCelebrity(celebrity, 4, true);
                            money = money - celebrity.getPrice();
                            myDb.updateValues("MONEY", money);
                            cursor.moveToNext();

                            int moneyPerClick = cursor.getInt(1);
                            moneyPerClick = moneyPerClick + celebrity.getIncrease();
                            myDb.updateValues("MONEY_PER_CLICK", moneyPerClick);
                            break;

                        case "s":
                            myDb.updateCelebrity(celebrity, 4, true);
                            money = money - celebrity.getPrice();
                            myDb.updateValues("MONEY", money);
                            cursor.moveToNext();

                            cursor.moveToNext();
                            int moneyPerSec = cursor.getInt(1);
                            moneyPerSec = moneyPerSec + celebrity.getIncrease();
                            myDb.updateValues("MONEY_PER_SEC", moneyPerSec);
                            break;

                        case "p":
                            showPrestigeWarning(celebrity);
                            showCelebrities();
                            showPurchaseSnackbar(celebrity.getName());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am only trying to do this because the break inside of my switch doesn't work. If you have other solutions, please share them forward.

Comment: The `break` should work, there is no problem I see. Do you mean that the other `case` are also getting executed?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean... How do you stop the others from executing?

Comment: "stop the others from executing" Is that the only requirement for you? What is the return type of `celebrity.getCharacteristic()`? Can you also provide a sample input which you get under `celebrity.getCharacteristic()`. Thanks

Comment: The return type of `celebrity.getCharacteristic()` is a char that is either "c", "s" or "p". Does that help in any way?

Comment: If the return type is a `char` then replace "c" with `c` and so on.

Comment: Did your problem get solved?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning create a local `boolean` and set or change it in the `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: Thanks but I would like it to fully stop once it has finished the case statement. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Need more data. I didn't get what you mean

Comment: I need it to exit the function and restart the fragment. The only problem is that once the case statement executes, it executes the ones below it.